# Rotate a 2d multivariate normal distribution in r

Tags: r, statistics

Say I have a 2d normal distribution, defined by a covariance matrix and center. How can I rotate this distribution around the origin?

For example:

```
library(MASS)
n = 100
mu = c(4,5)
Sigma = matrix(c(3,2, 2,3), nrow=2)

plot(mvrnorm(n=n, mu=mu, Sigma=Sigma))
```

Rotating the center point of the distribution is relatively easy:

```
theta = 90*pi/180 #Angle in radians
mu2 = c(mu[1]*cos(theta) - mu[2]*sin(theta),mu[2]*cos(theta) + mu[1]*sin(theta))
plot(mvrnorm(n=n, mu=mu2, Sigma=Sigma))
```

But how do I change Sigma to rotate the orientation of the distribution?

Comment: Define the rotation matrix as `rot<-  matrix(c(cos(theta),sin(theta),-sin(theta),cos(theta)),nrow=2)`; the `Sigma` should change in `rot %*% Sigma %*% t(rot)`.

Comment: Great, that works, thanks!